# SSH thorough 3 systems to transfer the Data

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris

We have 3 Systems here, I need to transfer data from the **Data Server** to the **test vm** the only way is through the **jump-host**. this daily process take long time. How do I automate this thing for daily bases.

```
Server Name IP Address    
Test VM     10.10.2.228    
jump-host   10.10.3.30  port 22022  
Data Server 10.10.2.12  port 22022
```

Comment: Want to transfer data.dump from Data Server to Test VM. this would be done via Jump-host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH port forwarding (aka tunneling) is probably the best bet.

There are a couple of considerations. If you have root privileges on the **jump-host**, you can configure SSHD to allow forwarding and use one command/session from **Data Server** to pass through **jump-host** to **test vm**. If you do not, you may still be able to complete the task, but it could take another ssh tunnel and perhaps other commands or applications.

Port forwarding is not too difficult if you understand the concepts, but it can be quite tricky at first when learning how to make it do as you wish.

**Caveat H@x0r**
Depending on the environment, policy, and security-guidance, this *could* be considered activity that circumvents security controls. You have been warned.

Rather than try to ascertain your specific situation, here are a few links that might prove useful:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-up-ssh-tunneling-on-a-linux-unix-bsd-server-to-bypass-nat/

Comment: > I don't have root access on jump-host

Comment: Still unable to do it, Cant find my way to the source & destination.

Comment: This was a bad idea my network had restricted those system.